# Several neighboring NestedScrollView in the bottom sheet

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

I have two NestedScrollView with a visibility switch in the BottomSheet. The problem is that BottomSheet scrolling works only for the first NestedScrollView in the sources.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem now, divided one BottomSheet into two. And programmatically change FABs *app:layout_anchor*.